# NestJS HTTPS empty @POST() body

Tags: javascript, typescript, https, nestjs

Im using NestJS via HTTPS.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { fstat } from 'fs';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import {readFileSync} from 'fs'
async function bootstrap() {
  const httpsOptions = {
    key:readFileSync('tsl/private-key.pem'),
    cert:readFileSync('tsl/public-cert.pem')
  }
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule,{httpsOptions});
  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

I try to get simple POST request:

```
 @Post()
   test(@Body() body){
     console.log(body);
  }
```

But output is always `{}`

POSTMAN:
[image: postman]

I readed that nestjs cant parse data correctly. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 23):

Your postman request needs to be set to `raw` and `JSON`, not `raw` and `Text`

Comment: Thank you!  But why it doesnt work from code? `let request = { name:'Mike'}; req.write(JSON.stringify(request))`

Comment: That would all depend on what your http client is. That information isn't provided in your question.

Comment: i use default https nodejs module

Comment: Do you set the `Content-Type` header? You really should be showing code in your question rather than in comments

Comment: Yep, i forgot `Content-Type`. Thank you, man

Answer (score -1):

Integrate swagger into your application.
It is an open API and supported by nestjs.
https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32708002)